# Use custom AndroidManifest.xml for instrumentation classes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want me Roboticum tests to use a custom (extended) version of my application context. I have the following AndroidManifest located under my test folder (notice the android:name=".RoboticumApplication"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bipper.app.bsafe.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.bipper.app.bsafe" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".RoboticumApplication">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
```

And defined it like this in my gradle.build

```
 androidTest {
         java.srcDirs = ['test-test/src']
         manifest.srcFile 'test-test/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
```

But I cant see its being used, it seems like the whole AndroidManifest file I point to in gradle is just ignored, in the log I dont see any indications that the constructor is being called in RoboticumApplication (I added logging in the constructor).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration),

> the sourceSet should not contain an AndroidManifest.xml as it is automatically generated.

I would like to modify the icon and app name too, and haven't yet figured out how to do this.

Comment: The documentation has changed by now

"The <instrumentation> node of the manifest for the test app is generated but you can create a src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml file to add other components to the test manifest."